# access layout object Qt 5

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I am following [this](https://www.packtpub.com/web-development/mastering-qt-5-second-edition) book and it builds some kind of todo GUI app. We firstly create a `MainWindow` class:

```
// MainWindow.hpp

#ifndef MAINWINDOW_HPP
#define MAINWINDOW_HPP

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QVector>
#include "Task.hpp" // <- irrelevant to my question

namespace Ui {
    class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow
    : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

public slots:
    void add_task();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;       // <- this is what I am having problems with
    QVector<Task*> m_tasks_vec;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_HPP
```

In the UI designer we add a couple of widgets and one is called `tasks_layout`:

[image]

Then we go on defining members of `MainWindow`:

```
// MainWindow.cpp
#include "MainWindow.hpp"
#include "ui_MainWindow.h"
#include <QDebug>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
    , m_tasks_vec()
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(ui->add_task_button, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MainWindow::add_task);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::add_task()
{
    qDebug() << "User clicked on the button!";
    auto default_task_name = "Untitled task";
    auto *task = new Task(default_task_name);
    m_tasks_vec.append(task);
    ui->tasks_layout->addWidget(task); // problem here
}
```

`ui->tasks_layout->addWidget(task);` part causes the problem:

> no member named 'tasks_layout' in 'Ui::MainWindow'

Looking at the picture above, it seems that `tasks_layout` maybe nested inside `centralWidget`, so I thought it might be typo in the book and tried `ui->centralWidget->tasks_layout->addWidget(task);`, but it didn't fix anything:

> no member named 'tasks_layout' in 'QWidget'

What am I doing wrong?

The closest thing to my question I found is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12659629/10147399), and it didn't help me

**This is the auto-generated ui_MainWindow.h:**

```
/********************************************************************************
** Form generated from reading UI file 'MainWindow.ui'
**
** Created by: Qt User Interface Compiler version 5.12.1
**
** WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost when recompiling UI file!
********************************************************************************/

#ifndef UI_MAINWINDOW_H
#define UI_MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QtCore/QVariant>
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets/QLabel>
#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
#include <QtWidgets/QMenuBar>
#include <QtWidgets/QPushButton>
#include <QtWidgets/QStatusBar>
#include <QtWidgets/QToolBar>
#include <QtWidgets/QWidget>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE

class Ui_MainWindow
{
public:
    QWidget *centralWidget;
    QLabel *status_label;
    QPushButton *add_task_button;
    QMenuBar *menuBar;
    QToolBar *mainToolBar;
    QStatusBar *statusBar;

    void setupUi(QMainWindow *MainWindow)
    {
        if (MainWindow->objectName().isEmpty())
            MainWindow->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("MainWindow"));
        MainWindow->resize(420, 361);
        centralWidget = new QWidget(MainWindow);
        centralWidget->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("centralWidget"));
        status_label = new QLabel(centralWidget);
        status_label->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("status_label"));
        status_label->setGeometry(QRect(10, 10, 111, 21));
        add_task_button = new QPushButton(centralWidget);
        add_task_button->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("add_task_button"));
        add_task_button->setGeometry(QRect(320, 10, 80, 21));
        MainWindow->setCentralWidget(centralWidget);
        menuBar = new QMenuBar(MainWindow);
        menuBar->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("menuBar"));
        menuBar->setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 420, 20));
        MainWindow->setMenuBar(menuBar);
        mainToolBar = new QToolBar(MainWindow);
        mainToolBar->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("mainToolBar"));
        MainWindow->addToolBar(Qt::TopToolBarArea, mainToolBar);
        statusBar = new QStatusBar(MainWindow);
        statusBar->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("statusBar"));
        MainWindow->setStatusBar(statusBar);

        retranslateUi(MainWindow);

        QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName(MainWindow);
    } // setupUi

    void retranslateUi(QMainWindow *MainWindow)
    {
        MainWindow->setWindowTitle(QApplication::translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", nullptr));
        status_label->setText(QApplication::translate("MainWindow", "Status: 0 todo / 0 done", nullptr));
        add_task_button->setText(QApplication::translate("MainWindow", "Add task", nullptr));
    } // retranslateUi

};

namespace Ui {
    class MainWindow: public Ui_MainWindow {};
} // namespace Ui

QT_END_NAMESPACE

#endif // UI_MAINWINDOW_H
```

Comment: Can you check the auto generated ui_MainWindow.h to see if it's updated with your ui design file ?

Comment: @jgoday How do I tell if it is updated and how do I update it if it's not already?

Comment: @Ayxan what build system are you using ? if you are using cmake, the autogenerated header would be under the build folder ...

Comment: @jgoday added relevant ui_MainWindow.h to the question

Comment: @Ayxan as you can see, it 's not updated

Comment: @jgoday how do I update it?

Comment: @Ayxan what build system are you using ? (sorry to ask it again), qmake, cmake ??

Comment: @jgoday Using qmake

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190435/discussion-between-jgoday-and-ayxan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your build system hasn't updated `ui_MainWindow.h` following changes to `MainWindow.ui`, it's also lacking the spacers. You need to ensure that it re-runs `uic`.

That *should* be done by QCreator's build action, but if it has gotten confused you may have to clean and/or rebuild.